# Office.js function not working in MVC application for Word Online

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-office, office365-apps, office-js

I have a .NET MVC project for Word online. The add-in starts up successfully but it does not load "Home.js" which calls Office.initialize to insert data into the body of word.

Here is _Layout.cshtml:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Office/1/office.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Home.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.min.js")
</body>
</html>
```

And Home.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (!Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', '1.1')) {
                return;
            }
            loadSampleData();
        });
    };

    function loadSampleData() {

        // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
        Word.run(function (context) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var body = context.document.body;
            // Queue a commmand to clear the contents of the body.
            body.clear();
            // Queue a command to insert text into the end of the Word document body.
            body.insertText("This is a sample text inserted in the document",
                            Word.InsertLocation.end);

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync();
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
    }

    function errorHandler(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    }
})();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Id also like to comment on the angular bootstrapping issue. I have tried taking out angular of the application completely and the issue persists.

Comment: Is home.js loading at all?  I.e., if you pu a console.log at the top, will it print? If yes, if you put a console.log as the first line inside of Office.initialze, will it print?

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes it does print.

Comment: If both are printing, could it be that isSetSupported('WordApi', '1.1') is failing?  It will only return true on 2016+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only executing if WordAPI v1.1 is available. This API is only supported in [Word 2016 for Windows, Mac and iPad](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/office-add-in-requirement-sets). If you're using Word Online or Word 2013 this code will exit (`return`) without executing anything.

One other note, you're referencing Office.js and Home.js at the bottom of the `<body>`. You only have 5 seconds to complete Office.initialize() and placing it at the bottom of the page will require everything load before the browser executes that function. While this is absolutely the proper thing to do for a web site, it will result in time-out errors with Add-ins. These references [should always be placed within the `<header>`](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn).